# Closing DAX Client in Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-elasticache, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I have a node.js functon that I want to deploy as a AWS Lambda function.  I have noticed that when I use redis Elasticache, I must close the connection I opened with redis.createClient or else the Lambda function times out.  I do this by simply calling the client's quit() method.  If I do this prior to issuing the Lambda callback, the Lambda function ends as expected.  If I do not, the Lambda function times out at whatever timeout interval I set.  In a test setting, I have a Lambda function that operated on the cache and terminates in 30 milliseconds.  Without the call to the redis client quit() method, the same Lambda function won't terminate before a 1 minute timeout.  I'm not sure, but I assume the Lambda function behaves this way because it doesn't know whether the function is done executing (even after the callback) since the redis connection is still active.

I'm not all that concerned about this because it's easy enough to call the quit() method.  The problem I am having is when I try to do something similar with a DynamoDB DAX client.  I can have the Lambda function access DynamoDB directly through my VPC endpoint and everything works fine.  If I use the DAX client, the modifications to the table actually take place (I inserted an item and can see that it is there), but the Lambda function always times out.

Here is some sample code:

```
const AmazonDaxClient = require('amazon-dax-client');
const AWS             = require('aws-sdk');
const config          = require('./config');

AWS.config.update(config.aws);
var ddbClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(config.dynamodb);
var dax = new AmazonDaxClient(config.dax);
var daxClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({service: dax });
```

If I just use the ddbClient, everything works.  If I use the daxClient, everything also works (inserts, deletes, updates, etc.), but the Lambda function times out.  Is there a similar quit() method for the daxClient that tells the DAX cluster I'm done and it can close all the connections cleanly?  I suspect the problem with this is that they want the daxClient to behave exactly like a normal ddbClient, and there is not a quit() method for the ddbClient.

Comment: You might try setting `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false`...  That should address the timeout for both DAX and redis, and allow you to establish these connections with global variables configured outside the handler, and make things a little faster since you don't have to initialize them with each function invocation.  (I'm not familiar with the DAX client, but Lambda waits if anybody leaves a socket open, without this option.)

Comment: Michael, that did the trick on both fronts.  Thanks!  Do you want to write up an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the Lambda `context` property `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop`,  as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html#nodejs-prog-model-context-properties), may be relevant to your case. By default it is set to `true`, which means that even if your handler returns a value via callback, as long as there is anything still in the Node event loop, the Lambda won't complete its execution.

Setting it to `false` will allow your Lambda handler to complete even with things in the event loop, but be aware that these logical threads will freeze execution while the Lambda is not running. This behavior might not be appropriate for all libraries, depending on how robust they are.

On an interesting side note, the old Lambda return style of calling `context.succeed` (rather than `callback`) will not wait for an empty event loop, regardless of the property's setting. ([This gist](https://gist.github.com/hassy/eaea5a958067211f2fed02ead13c2678) goes into some extra detail.)

Comment: Just to be clear, this solution does work, but I'm not sure what Lambda is waiting on in the event loop.  I only issue the Lambda callback in a callback from the cache write.  So as far as I know, there should be nothing else waiting in the event loop.  I only have an active connection to the cache which I am finished with.  Issuing a quit() with the redis cache solved the problem, but there is nothing similar with DAX.  After testing this method with DAX, I found that all the writes to DynamoDB were there even when setting callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop to false.

Comment: Without investigating the DAX client code, I couldn't tell you, but it's likely leaving some kind of file handle (network connection?) open which keeps the event loop from emptying entirely for efficiency reasons.

Comment: I took a deep dive into the code to try and see what was going on (as it was causing problems other places as well).  It looks like they're not cleaning up their socket connections when they're done with them.

Comment: @ShannonWrege have you seen any other performance problems with your lambda functions use DAX since fixing this specific issue?  I was considering using it, but the ability of the client to clean up after itself seems kind of important to me.

Comment: Yeah, I was just evaluating DAX to possibly get rid of my own caching using a Redis Elasticache.  I already have everything implemented, and it is working well, so I have stopped investigating it for now.

Comment: Did any of guys, found any memory issues with using this flag?

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.1.2 of the DAX JS client, this is no longer an issue - the Lambda event loop will pause correctly when using DAX.

Comment: I have installed 1.1.2, and 1.1.3 and this problem persists. did u ever observe this issue, which versions did u observe with?