# Very lazy speed of scanning in Lambda and DAX for DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, lambda, aws-lambda, dax

I'm getting a problem using Lambda and DAX.

In lambda, Without Nodejs DAX clien the scan average time is 900ms but If I use DAX, it's 4500ms. It's weird because if I use DAX, estimated time will be short than before.

This is latest code. In here I'm only getting one record but still it's same. )

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const AmazonDaxClient = require('amazon-dax-client');
const config = require('../config.json');

AWS.config.update({
    region: config.region,
    accessKeyId: config.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: config.secretAccessKey
});

var dax = null;
var daxClient=null;

const daxConfig = {
    endpoints:[config.daxEndpoints],
    region:config.region
}
if(dax == null & daxClient == null) {
    console.log('initialized');
    dax = new AmazonDaxClient(daxConfig);
    daxClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({service: dax });
}

exports.main = function(event, context, callback) {

    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false

    const params = {
        TableName: "game_dev"
    };

    daxClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));

        } else {
            console.log("Query succeeded.");

        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: How many MB are you assigning to the Lambda?  Just checking on your average comment, does it take 4500ms per DynamoDb call if you call it one after the other?  If so, may I see the whole Lambda function?  What I'm curious about is whether you are instantiating the DynamoDb client every call or if you're initializing the DynamoDb call once, then reusing the already initialized client each call...

Comment: Thank you for response. I will attach the whole code.

Comment: 128MB memory is used for lambda. This is the code I used. Yes. you're right, it's called everytime via API Gateway. please help me if you have some idea.

Comment: Hello @Zaxxon, How can I reuse the already initialized client each call? please let me know how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Looking further at your code, a "scan" call is a slow call. A "scan" acts like a "Table Scan", meaning it will touch every record in your table.  I recommend using "query" where you can query by the "Primary partition key".  If you need to search by fields other than the "Primary partition key" you should consider other options like, ElasticSearch etc.  What are you trying to do?  Do you allow the user to search on any field in game_dev?

Comment: I'm trying to get all records in DB without specific condition. this is not recommended method?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hmm, how many records do you have?  How much data per record?  What do you need all the data for?  Do you only need some of the data and not all of it?

Comment: The payload size is only 14kb and about 50 records haha, I also used query call instead of scan but same. maybe is there a missing configuration?

Comment: Hmm, go ahead and post your latest code.

Comment: I have posted the latest code. as you can see, it's querying only one record(Id is partition key).

Comment: Fun, try the code this guy has "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47401616/closing-dax-client-in-lambda-function" above your handler and see how that works.  You'll have to adjust it somewhat give your paths, plus stripping out the code in your handler.

Comment: Also not sure you need the access key and pwd.  That doesn't seem right to have to include that as you are already.... hold on, are you testing this from your local machine against DynamoDb in the cloud or are you deploying this to AWS then testing in AWS against DynamoDb...  Also, are your Lambda and DynamoDb table in the same AWS region?  Also will want to only do the config once..

Comment: Oh my god. It's working well. Thank you. I have posted my final code. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad to hear!  One more nit, the extra "var"s in the if statement should probably be removed as it is kind of weird. (i.e. double var-ing dax and daxclient).  Also, when you have time, look for some other example of folk using nodejs against DynamoDb and I think you'll be able to make the code smaller and cleaner.  Have a great day!

Comment: How can you connect to DAX with Lambda? Is your Lambda in VPC?

Comment: Yes. that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Lambda uses reusable containers.  On first load it is an "initialized container".  2nd load on out till it refreshes (4hrs?) it reuses the initialized container. It may even scale out depending on the workload.

The trick you need to master in your code is to not reinitialize the DynamoDb client on each call.  This AWS link goes into more detail on it:  [AWS Best Practices on AWS Service Client Initialization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.BestPracticesWithDynamoDB.html)

So for your case, set up your client variables, dax and daxclient, outside the scope of the function handler.  In C# I declare them outside the scope of the handler then initialize them in the handler if they are null.  If not null I skip initialization and reuse.  Not sure what best practice is for nodejs though.

Comment: Hi Zaxxon, I did that with your idea. set up dax and daxclient outside the scope of the function. so that daxclient var is initialized once now. but the  query time is same like before.

Comment: The first run is slow because of the "cold start" issue.  (i.e. Things take time to initialize.)  How slow is it the second time you call it?

Comment: Hi Zaxxon. I'd like to get one more help. I don't understand the exact meaning of this graph. can you explain about that in a short work?

Comment: Hmm, don't know.  Are those DynamoDb graphs?  What does the little "i" say about the graphs?